# Error when compiling: Declaration of X must be compatible with Y

Tags: magento2.4, upgrade, magento-upgrade

I'm new to Magento and working on upgrading an existing project to 2.4.3. When running `php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile` I'm encountering an error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of X\RecurringService\Model\Export\MetadataProvider::getHeaders(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface $component) must be compatible with Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider::getHeaders(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface $component): array in /code/X/RecurringService/Model/Export/MetadataProvider.php on line 82
```

That points to the following:

```
/**
 * Retrieve Headers row array for Export
 *
 * @param UiComponentInterface $component
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getHeaders(UiComponentInterface $component)
{
    return array(
        'Next Delivery Date',
        'Service?',
        'Diaper#',
        'Wipes',
        'Doublers',
        'Name',
        'Address 1',
        'Address 2',
        'Exchange Notes',
        'Old #s',
        'Action Date',
        'Action Req',
        'Driver Date',
        'Driver Action',
        'Driver',
        'Status'
    );
}
```

I'm guessing this is the result of something changing in the new version, but can't seem to find any explanation or docs referencing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function code with below as your function is not compatible with the Magento's core function.
You missed the function as array `: array`

Then run `setup:di:compile` command

```
/**
 * Retrieve Headers row array for Export
 *
 * @param UiComponentInterface $component
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getHeaders(UiComponentInterface $component): array
{
    return array(
        'Next Delivery Date',
        'Service?',
        'Diaper#',
        'Wipes',
        'Doublers',
        'Name',
        'Address 1',
        'Address 2',
        'Exchange Notes',
        'Old #s',
        'Action Date',
        'Action Req',
        'Driver Date',
        'Driver Action',
        'Driver',
        'Status'
    );
}
```

Hope this will hep you!